# Fortran "Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)”

Tags: function, fortran, fortran90

I ran into this error while coding, and cannot find any legit reason for it. I have called and executed functions like this before. The code is:

```
implicit none
real et(5),k(5,4),v(5),f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,kk,t,h
integer i,j
do i=1,5
et(i)=i-1.0
v(i)=0.0
end do
h=0.01
kk=6.0
do j=1,1000
write(*,*) et(1),et(2),et(3),et(4),et(5),t
do i=1,5
et(i)=et(i)+h*v(i)
end do
k(1,1)=h*f1(et(1),et(2),t) !partcle,k_no
k(2,1)=h*f2(et(1),et(2),et(3),t)
k(3,1)=h*f3(et(2),et(3),et(4),t)
k(4,1)=h*f4(et(3),et(4),et(5),t)
k(5,1)=h*f5(et(4),et(5),t)  
k(1,2)=h*f1(et(1)+0.5*k(1,1),et(2)+0.5*k(2,1),t+0.5*h)  
k(2,2)=h*f2(et(1)+0.5*k(1,1),et(2)+0.5*k(2,1),et(3)+0.5*k(3,1),
 +      t+0.5*h)
k(3,2)=h*f3(et(2)+0.5*k(2,1),et(3)+0.5*k(3,1),et(4)+0.5*k(4,1),
 +  t+0.5*h)
k(4,2)=h*f4(et(3)+0.5*k(3,1),et(4)+0.5*k(4,1),et(5)+0.5*k(5,1),
 +  t+0.5*h)
k(5,2)=h*f5(et(4)+0.5*k(4,1),et(5)+0.5*k(5,1),t+0.5*h)
k(1,3)=h*f1(et(1)+0.5*k(1,2),et(2)+0.5*k(2,2),t+0.5*h)
k(2,3)=h*f2(et(1)+0.5*k(1,2),et(2)+0.5*k(2,2),et(3)+0.5*k(3,2),
 +  t+0.5*h)
k(3,3)=h*f3(et(2)+0.5*k(2,2),et(3)+0.5*k(3,2),et(4)+0.5*k(4,2),
 +  t+0.5*h)
k(4,3)=h*f4(et(3)+0.5*k(3,2),et(4)+0.5*k(4,2),et(5)+0.5*k(5,2),
 +  t+0.5*h)
k(5,3)=h*f5(et(4)+0.5*k(4,2),et(5)+0.5*k(5,2),t+0.5*h)
k(1,4)=h*f1(et(1)+k(1,1),et(2)+k(2,1),t+h)
k(2,4)=h*f2(et(1)+k(1,1),et(2)+k(2,1),et(3)+k(3,1),t+h)
k(3,4)=h*f3(et(2)+k(2,1),et(3)+k(3,1),et(4)+k(4,1),t+h)
k(4,4)=h*f4(et(3)+k(3,1),et(4)+k(4,1),et(5)+k(5,1),t+h)
k(5,4)=h*f5(et(4)+k(4,1),et(5)+k(5,1),t+h)

do i=1,5
v(i)=v(i)+(1.0/6.0)*(k(1,i)+2*k(2,i)+2*k(3,i)+k(4,i))
end do

end do

end program


real function f1(et(1),et(2),t)


f1=kk*(et(2)-et(1))+cos(2*t)
return
end function

real function f2(et(1),et(2),et(3),t)

f2=kk*(et(3)-2*et(2)+et(1))
return
end function


real function f3(et(2),et(3),et(4),t)

f3=kk*(et(4)-2*et(3)+et(2))
return
end function

real function f4(et(3),et(4),et(5),t)
f4=kk*(et(5)-2*et(4)+et(3))
return
end function

real function f5(et(4),et(5),t) 

f5=kk*(et(4)-et(5))
return
end function
```

when compiled only gives this error :

```
  implicit none                                                     
                                                                    1


  real function f1(et(1),et(2),t)                                   
                                                                    2
Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)
```

Can you please suggest debugging? Is there some issue in calling a function with arrays as argument?

Comment: in this case your best approach may be to pass the entire array as a single argument

Comment: @agentp But he passes things like `et(4)+0.5*k(4,1)`

Comment: in those cases the argument passed in would be `et+k(:,1)/2` , with a length 5 array as the dummy argument in the subroutine.

Comment: Probably a silly suggestion... Is it my impression or the statement `program myprogram` is missing at the very top of the code? Could it be causing the "Two main programs" issue?

Comment: @Aristotelis i tried that too. Turns out it is not mandatory to mention it, though it is a good practice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot name your variables or dummy arguments with parentheses:

```
 real function f1(et(1),et(2),t)
```

You must name them normally with alphabetic characters and numbers only

```
 real function f1(et1,et2,t)
```

Comment: what i meant to do there was to use elements from an array as arguments. so function "f1" has the first element of array "et" as one of its arguments. how do i execute that without using parentheses?

Comment: Why do you need to see them as array elements in the function?

Comment: i thought the arguments for the function need to be declared in the exact format as they appear in the main program. They are array elements in the main program.

Comment: No they do not, there is no reason for that.